# Qt sdk for ubuntu development creating 3 Qml2puppet upon design mode

Tags: 12.10, 13.04, qt, qml, qt-creator

When I create a project in Qt Creator 2.7.1 on Ubuntu 13.04 64bit the project is all fine.
But when I enter the design mode on the left side menu, then there are 3 instances of Qml2puppet appearing on the screen.

Why is this happening?

The design mode is running fine on Windows 7 with just single window of Qml2puppet upon entering the Design mode.

I have also observed this problem on Ubuntu 12.10 version

Is there any patch or any other solution that I can apply to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is the feedback from #ubuntu-touch I got about this when I asked in the middle of June:

> (21:22:54) vadi: Also in the Welcome tab, when I click on the Develop tab, I get a whole lot of unresponsive windows opened. Is this known?
>   (21:23:04) vadi: About four of them...
>   (21:23:23) popey: I have seen that before, yes
>   (21:23:40) vadi: Okay
>   (21:23:52) popey: I had to clear out my .config/QtProject folder to fix that iirc

Comment: It didn't work for me...